# Insert data via SSIS package and different datatypes

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, type-conversion

I have a table with a column1 nvarchar(50) null. I want to insert this into a more 'tight' table with a nvarchar(30) not null. My idea was to insert a derived column task between source and destination task with this expression: Replace column1 = **(DT_WSTR,30)Column1**

I get the "truncation may occur error" and I am not allowed to insert the data into the new tighter table.

Also I am 100% sure that no values are over 30 characters in the column. Moreover I do not have the possibility to change the column data type in the source.

What is the best way to create the ETL process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider changing the truncation error disposition of the Derived Column component within your Data Flow. By default, a truncation will cause the Derived Column component to fail. You can configure the component to ignore or redirect rows which are causing a truncation error.

To do this, open the Derived Column Transformation editor and click the 'Configure Error Output...' button in the bottom-left of the dialog. From here, change the setting in the 'Truncation' column for any applicable columns as required.

[image: Row Error Disposition Settings]

Be aware that any data which is truncated for columns ignoring failure will not be reported by SSIS during execution. It sounds like you've already done this, but it's important to be sure you've analysed your data as it currently stands and taken into consideration any possible future changes to the nature of the data before disabling truncation reporting.

Answer (score 1):

JotaBe recommended using a data conversion transformation.  Yes, that is another way to achieve the same thing, but it will also error out if truncation occurs.  Your way *should* work (I tried it), provided the input data really is less than 30 characters.

You could modify your derived column expression to

```
(DT_WSTR,30)Substring([Column1], 1, 30)
```

Comment: Can you check if the data type of the output column of the derived column task is the required one? I don't have SSIS to check it right now.

Comment: Some time has gone by sice I don't use SSIS, but I remembered that made me crazy. However, I wasn't sure, so I asked you to chek it.

Comment: your original answer wors perfectly. You can remove the comment. WHen you create a derived column you can set the output column data type, and it works perfectly. Or even better, check the transformation and see if it allows you to check the data type. Perhaps in older versions it was not possible (I doubt it) but now it is.

Answer (score 0):

To do so you must use a [Data Conversion Transformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141706.aspx), which allows to change the data type from the original nvarchar(50) to the desired nvarchar(30).

You'll get a new column with the required data type.

Of course, you can decide what to do in case of error: truncation, by configuring this component.

**UPDATE**

As there are people who have downvoted this answer, let's add 3 more comments:

1. this solution is checked and works. Create a table with a nvarchar(50) column, a new table with a nvarchar(30) column, add a data flow that uses a data conversion transform and it works witout a glitch. Please, chek it, I guarantee. Besides, as the OP states "Also I am 100% sure that no values are over 30 characters in the column" in his case there will be no truncation problems. However, I recommend treating the possible errors, just in case they happen.
2. from MSDN: `"a package can perform the following types of data conversions: ... Set the column length of string data"`
3. from MSDN: `"If the length of an output column of string data is shorter than the length of its corresponding input column, the output data is truncated."`

Comment: It would be interesting to know why there are two downvotes on an answer which works (you can try it) and besides is well documentented on MSDN. It would be great to know the reason of the downvotes.